# powershell match string then replace another

Tags: powershell

I want to use PowerShell to manipulate a file. The tab-delimited file is as follows:

> Data     Sector1
>   Data1    Sector1
>   Work    Sector1
>   Work1   Sector1

I want to find the records that start with "Work" and replace "Sector1" with "NewVal". The output should look like this:

> Data    Sector1
>   Data1     Sector1
>   Work     **NewVal**
>   Work1     **NewVal**

I used to be able to do this in UNIX by using:
 s/Work/Sector1/**NewVal**
but I can't figure out the PowerShell equivalent.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a RegEx match to do this with little trouble.

Get-Content C:\Path\To\File.txt | ForEach{$_ -replace "(?<=^Work.*?\s)Sector1", "NewVal"} | Set-Content C:\Path\To\File.txt

Comment: Thanks! This is really close. I'm getting an error:"Set-Content : The process cannot access the file 'C:\Path\To\File.txt' because it is being used by another process". I've confirmed that there isn't another handle on the file. It seems to be blocking itself. -Force didn't work. Thinking of writing to a temp file then renaming it back to the original. Is there a better solution?

Comment: You could put parenthesis around most of the command to make it complete all the replacements and then write the file. `(Get-Content C:\Path\To\File.txt | ForEach{$_ -replace "(?<=^Work.*?\s)Sector1", "NewVal"})| Set-Content C:\Path\To\File.txt`

Answer (score 0):

As long as your source file contains header columns "key" and "value" the following will be able to accomplish this and write to a new csv file.  Please note that the contains method here is a case sensitive pattern match against "Work".

```
import-csv .\sourcefile.csv | foreach-object {
    if (($_.key).contains("Work")) {
        $_.value = "NewVal"
    }
    $_ | export-csv -Append .\newFile.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: If he wants to maintain it be tab delimited he needs `Export-CSV -Delim "`t" .\newfile.csv -notype`